# true or false questions on functions

Tags: real-analysis

These are a few problems on functions which I could not solve.

Which of the statements are true?

1. There is a continuous bijection from $\mathbb{R}^2$ → $\mathbb{R}$.
2. There is a bijection between $\mathbb{Q}$ and  $\mathbb{Q} × \mathbb{Q} $.
3. If $f : [0; 1] → [-π,π]$ is a continuous bijection then it is a homeomorphism.

Help me please.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Some hints:

1. Let $\Delta$ be a triangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$. What would the image of $\Delta$ in $\mathbb{R}$ look like?
2. $\mathbb{Q}$ is bijective with $\mathbb{N}$.  Is there a bijection $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$?
3. For $f$ to be a homeomorphism and not just a continuous bijection, it needs to map open sets to open sets, or equivalently (since $f$ is a bijection), closed sets to closed sets.  Can you think of a reason why $f$ maps closed (hence compact) subsets of $[0,1]$ to closed subsets of $[-\pi,\pi]$?